# Twitter Api 1.1 , Get feeds using ngCordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, twitter, phonegap-plugins, twitter-oauth

I have been working on twitter feed in cordova using angularjs.
I have created app in my account and have generated consumer key and secret key and also access token.

[User cordova-twitter plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-twitter,)
[cordovaOauth](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/)

I have tried this few links but nothing working for me.
Please help me out with this issue as am beginner with this twitter and could'nt find any tutorial for beginners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone. 
I found it difficult to implement twitter in cordova. Hence i went in other way. I have used PHP to get feeds from twitter and then call that api in my app.
Integrating in php was much simpler. But still if some one has better idea please post it here, it might be helpfull in future.